# Errors after update to xcode 7.0.1 - append

Tags: xcode, swift, append, xcode7

I recently upgraded Xcode 7 to Xcode 7.0.1, and now my code seems to be broken.

```
var geog = [(cap:String(),paese:String(),moneta:String())]

geog.append(cap:"Roma",paese:"Italia",moneta:"Euro") // error here
```

The error is: `cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of .......`

The same code worked with Swift 1, and even worked with Swift 2, however it seems to be completely broken now.

I have hundreds of lines of code with this error and i don't want to rewrite them all if it worked before. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting:

`geog.append(cap:"Roma",paese:"Italia",moneta:"Euro")`

to:

`geog.append((cap:"Roma",paese:"Italia",moneta:"Euro"))`

Comment: thanks, i knew the solution was simple, how can i automatize this process?i have hundreds of lines to fix

Comment: @GioB: I'm surprised Apple didn't include this change in their release notes. Albeit subtle, it is very troublesome to track.

Comment: @GioB: I don't really know how you can properly automate this process without breaking other code. Even if you batch replace `append(cap:` with `append((cap:`, you've still got the closing  parentheses to worry about.

Comment: i started with that, i hoped there was something faster